# Doc for onActivityResult?

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I was browsing through GDAA demo [here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/spjanson/gdaademo/MainActivity.java) when I came across something very interesting. The programmer is using `onActivityResult` for four different actions but the `startActivityForResult()` is called only for one action. Of the other actions, two of them use `startIntentSenderForResult` and one uses `startResolutionForResult`. I have since seen other SO questions expecting the result for these in `onActivityResult` but I am unable to find any doc that says what all methods call `onActivityResult`.

Does anyone has the proper link?

Answer (score 1):

There is no one place where this is documented :-( `startIntentSenderForResult()` is used in `Fragment` and `startResolutionForResult()` is used in the Google Play APIs. In the future there may be other ways to start an `Activity` and return a result.

Comment: Actually the above example uses `startIntentSenderForResult` from a Activity itself. I don't think I have ever come across undocumented piece of code before.

Comment: Developer documentation for `Activity` describes `startIntentSenderForResult()` by saying it works like `startActivityForResult()`. What exactly do you mean that you have never come across undocumented code before? Is that meant to be a joke, or sarcasm, or are you being serious?

Comment: Yes, it says it works like that but it doesn't mention where we can expect it to deliver the result. I guess I should have worded it better. I would say that it is not properly documented.

Comment: A lot of Android is poorly documented or not documented. That's why you have Stackoverflow ;-)